# Kiln does not show changesets after successfully pushing changes using TortoiseHg/Mercurial

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tortoisehg, kiln

I pushed all my changesets to my repository on kiln. If you look under the column `Phase`, it says my changesets are public

http://snag.gy/1E87x.jpg

but, as of a week ago, none of my changes show up on my repository on kiln despite getting a green 'Success' label whenever I push those changes.

http://snag.gy/nREXB.jpg

here is what my log looks like

http://snag.gy/gZMDW.jpg

not sure what the problem is, anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you re-asking the same question? Also, if the url contains sensitive information, you might want to consider also masking the "Clone URL" in the kiln screenshot.

Comment: not really sensitive, just habit. Thanks for pointing that out. I reposted because I wanted to ask the question differently with different information presented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out The Kiln Queueing Service was not started on the server